# How to get api endpoint by operationId in openapi

Tags: swagger, openapi

I just wanted to know if there is any nodejs library or npm package which will take operationId as input and return full api endpoint.
Ofcourse I can create a function which could implement brute-force with one stack and would return the full api endpoint.
But I am looking for a library or npm package

Answer (score 1):

Try this package : **swagger-autogen**
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-autogen`

This module can identify the endpoints and automatically capture methods such as to get, post, put, and so on